# How do I use Ruby to connect to a MySql database outside of Rails as a scripting language

Tags: mysql, ruby, database-connection

Hi Im using Ruby as a scripting language. Not for web development, but to connect to a local database on my computer and manipulate it.

Id like to know how I can connect. Do I need to download/import tools? What do I need to get started?

Thanks,

---

Update

I did gem install mysql2 and ran the following ruby file

```
require 'mysql2'  

#my = Mysql.new(hostname, username, password, databasename)  
con = Mysql.new('localhost', 'nverma', 'something', 'ruby')  
rs = con.query('select * from contacts')  
rs.each_hash { |h| puts h['name']}  
con.close
```

and got the following error:-

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext
 /kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2 
 /mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
 Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
 Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext 
 /kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext
 /kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext
 /kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext
 /kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
 from sol5.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Please help!

Comment: Look at the `mysql2` gem.

Comment: Please have a look on the updated question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the `mysql2` gem:

```
gem install mysql2
```

Connect to your database:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")
```

Query the database:

```
results = client.query("SELECT * FROM users")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your update, is the `Mysql` class your own class? If so can you post that code also?

If not and you are trying to use mysql2 directly here, then you need instantiate the db connection the way @infused said in the other answer:

```
con = Mysql2::Client.new(host: "localhost", username: "root")
```